# How to capture email and autofill a form?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

guys! Hope that you're having a marvelous day.

I have a "Schedule a demo" form on https://scalr.intl-l.com/ (right in the hero section)

When the client adds his email and clicks on "Schedule a Demo with a Solutions Engineer", the website should redirect him to https://get.scalr.com/demo-request/ and autofill his email in the "Business Email" field.

The question is: How can I capture his email with the form on homepage and autofill his email later on in the "request demo" form?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us some code.

Comment: You can use $_GET parameters and add his email there.

Answer (score 0):

On the user entering his email you can redirect him to the page with javascript and add the parameters as GET parameters like this :

```
$(location).attr('href', 'https://get.scalr.com/demo-request?email=foo@bar.baz')
```

After that you can simply check if there is a '$_GET['email']' parameter set it in the input field like this:

```
<?php echo $_GET['email'] ? $_GET['email'] : ''; ?>
```

P.S. : Obviously for this way you will need jQuery. It's possible to do it with vanilla JS, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690095/5890686) for explanation.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it today

Comment: Sure, hope that it helps you. Also if you choose this as the answer, it would be very nice. Thanks !

Comment: <div class="col span_5">
<h3>Schedule a Scalr Demo</h3>
<h5>with a solution engineer</h5>
</div>

<div class="col span_6">
<form action="#" method="post" name="sign up for beta form">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="text" class="button" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Business Email">
        <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="Get Started">
      </div>
    </form>
</div>

Here's my html form. Where do I need to add the script?

Comment: You can add the script on the submission event. So after a user has send the email, you can redirect them to the desired location. After that it's just a matter of pasting the latter code as the value of the input. Hope that this helps.